# Find the unique column combinations

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the unique combination. The sequence is not important so 1 - 3 and 3 - 1 is the same. I'm stuck at:

```
SELECT column1, column2, count(*)
FROM testTable
GROUP BY column1, column2
```

Example:

```
id      column1     column2
1       1           3
2       3           2
3       3           1
4       1           2
5       2           1
6       2           3
7       1           2
8       3           2
9       1           3
10      3           2
```

End result:

```
column1     column2     count
1           2           3
1           3           3
2           3           4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use `least` and `greatest` with aggregation:

```
select least(column1,column2) as column1, 
       greatest(column1,column2) as column2, 
       count(*) as cnt
from testtable
group by least(column1,column2), greatest(column1,column2)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/633e6/2)

Comment: Beware of the behavior of `least` and `greatest` functions when any of the arguments is NULL. This is probably not an issue in this particular case, we probably have a(n unstated) guarantee  that `column1` and `column2` won't ever be NULL. In the more general case, the behavior with NULL values can be an unexpected gotcha. The workaround is to use expressions like `IF(col1<col2,col1,col2) AS least_`

Comment: @spencer7593 -- good point, if `column1` or `column2` can contain null values, then the `least` and `greatest` would return null for both columns.  Depends on sample data and desired results if null values exist.