# Find unique combinations of two columns optimizing for performance

Tags: sql, presto

Given a table like the one below, how can I write a SQL query to find the unique combinations of `col1` and `col2` without using array functions or `LEAST()`/`GREATEST()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085522/find-the-unique-column-combinations). I was wondering if there is a self-join option. I'm optimizing for performance.

```
SELECT
    t.col1,
    t.col2
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('1212', '2323'),
        ('2323', '1212'),
        ('3434', '1212'),
        ('3434', '4545')
) AS t(col1, col2)
```

The desired outcome should be 3 as there are only three unique combinations of `col1` and `col2`.

Comment: Why do you think `LEAST` and `GREATEST` are slow? I guess using them is fine here.

Comment: What do you mean unique combinations of col1 and col2? Please elaborate

Comment: @JonasMetzler Not that they are slow, but looking to see if there is a better way than that.

Comment: @drum In the example table above, there are 3 unique combinations since '1212', '2323' and '2323', '1212' should be counted as 1 combination and not 2.

Comment: Use a case statement to get the lower value as one column and another case statement to get the higher value - then run a select distinct